# How to configure wildfly 10 for jersey rest service?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0, wildfly-10

I tried this jersey hello world tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060073/RESTFul-Web-Service-Using-Jersey-x-Part-I
I have a welcome file index.html and a rest url /rest/message/helloworld

I could deploy the war successfully in tomcat 9 and everything works fine.

I deployed the same war file on wildfly 10 but rest url is not working:

1. it deployed successfully as i could see in the admin panel.
2. I can access the welcome file index.html and it shows the simple hello

But I can not access the rest url which says Not Found. The same thing worked on Tomcat perfectly. Do Wildfly needs some configuration for Jersey bases rest?

I'm using Jersey 2.6.

Comment: Why? Use the built in rest-easy support. [RESTEasy JAX-RS](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Wildfly does not need Jersey - it already includes a JAX-RS implementation.  If I may recommend a simpler solution for JEE servers...

You need 3 files:

`RestApplicationConfig.java`

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * Used to bootstrap JAX-RS.  Otherwise this class is
 * not directly used.
 *
 */
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

`HeartbeatService.java`

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Provides a simple heartbeat.
 *
 */
@Path("/v1/heartbeat")
public class HeartbeatService {

    /**
     * Get the heartbeat.  Basically if you can hit this "service"
     * then the machine and process are up.
     * 
     * @return a HTTP 200 with a simple "OK" text response packet.
     * 
     */
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @GET
    public Response getHeartBeat() {
        return Response.ok("OK").build();
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-simple-sample</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.hotjoe.jaxrs</groupId>
    <name>JAXRS Simple Sample</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

(Taken from my [github example](https://github.com/stdunbar/jaxrs-simple-sample/tree/master))

Once you build you'll access the REST service at http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-simple-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/v1/heartbeat

If you'd prefer the service that is shown in the example could replace the simple service above.

An important note - this is a JavaEE project - it will **not** run under Tomcat as it takes advantage of libraries and facilities that are included in a full JavaEE server.  Tomcat implements the servlet/jsp portion of the JavaEE spec (and a few other parts) but not the JAX-RS part.  However, this should run almost unchanged for Glassfish.  The only change would be in the pom.xml.

Comment: I will try this. So what I understand is, there is an inbuilt implementation of JAX-RS in wildfly called RestEasy and can be used. What if I have an existing project completely build on Jersey 2.x and want to deploy on wildfly?

Comment: It depends on how much of the Jersey libraries you're using.  If it's only things like the code in web.xml then it's very straightforward.  If your code is using Jersey libraries directly then it's harder.  If that is the case you may be better off sticking with Glassfish for now.  But realistically your best bet is to move to a pure JAX-RS implementation so you're not directly dependent on RestEasy or Jersey.